# Formatando String em Python para ter aparência de endereço MAC

Tags: python, string, formatação

Preciso transformar um MAC em string e deixar dois pontos a cada 2 caracteres, seria possível?

```
import re

mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
novo = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","",mac)

b0be762931b3 #ele retorna esse mac.
```

Tendo a seguinte string: `b0be762931b3`

Eu gostaria que ela ficasse assim: `b0:be:76:29:31:b3`.

Answer (score 9):

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.8 pode fazer assim:

```py
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
print(bytes.fromhex(mac.replace('-', '')).hex(':'))
```

Afinal, o *MAC Address* está representado em hexadecimal, portanto [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) consegue convertê-lo para `bytes` sem problemas (depois de remover os hífens, claro).

Em seguida, o [ḿetodo `hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) converte os bytes de volta para hexadecimal, mas usando o `:` como separador. O detalhe é que o resultado terá letras minúsculas, independente do valor original (ou seja, se a string for `'B5B4-7422-37BC'`, o resultado ainda será `b5:b4:74:22:37:bc`.

Mas como já dito, isso só funciona a partir do Python 3.8, pois em versões anteriores o método `hex` não aceita o separador como parâmetro.

---

Para versões anteriores ao 3.8 você pode usar as soluções das outras respostas, mas apenas para deixar registrado mais algumas alternativas:

```py
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
macbytes = bytes.fromhex(mac.replace('-', ''))
formatado = ':'.join(f'{b:02x}' for b in macbytes)
print(formatado)
```

Esta solução também cria um objeto `bytes`, mas formata cada byte para hexadecimal antes de passar para `join`. Para tal, é usado uma [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), que está disponível a partir do Python 3.6 - em versões anteriores pode trocar para `format`:

```
formatado = ':'.join('{:02x}'.format(b) for b in macbytes)
```

Lembrando ainda que esta opção resulta em letras minúsculas. Para letras maiúsculas, troque o formato para `02X`.

---

Outro jeito:

```py
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"

mac = mac.replace('-', '')
formatado = ':'.join(mac[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(mac), 2))
print(formatado)
```

É similar a [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/541329/112052), mas usando [*slices*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) para pegar pedaços da string (sempre de 2 em 2 caracteres), e no final juntando tudo com `join`, usando o `:` como separador. Mas ao contrário do que foi feito lá, eu não usei os colchetes em volta da expressão, pois isso cria uma lista desnecessariamente (claro que para uma string pequena como essa é um *overhead* imperceptível, mas enfim).

---

E já que você usou regex, também daria para ser assim:

```py
import re
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"

formatado = ':'.join(m[0] for m in re.finditer('[a-f0-9]{2}', mac, re.I))
print(formatado)
```

Como o MAC Address está representado em hexadecimal, só vai ter letras de "a" até "f", então não preciso colocar até o "z" na regex. Também usei a [opção `re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) para que ela seja *case insensitive* (pegue tanto maiúsculas quanto minúsculas).

E usei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2}` para pegar exatamente dois caracteres. Ou seja, `finditer` retornará as letras e números, agrupados de 2 em 2 (e repare que **nem precisa de `replace` ou `sub` para remover os hífens**, pois estes serão ignorados pela regex - ou seja, em vez de usar a regex para remover os hífens, eu uso para capturar os caracteres que preciso).

No `join` eu pego o grupo zero de cada *match*, que contém os caracteres que foram capturados.

Outra alternativa com regex é:

```py
import re
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"

formatado = ':'.join(re.findall('[a-f0-9]{2}', mac, re.I))
print(formatado)
```

A diferença é que [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna uma lista (ou seja, primeiro ela constrói uma lista com todos os trechos que deram *match*, e depois passa-a para `join`), enquanto [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) retorna um *iterator* (ou seja, ele não constrói uma lista, e em vez disso ele vai obtendo cada *match* de uma vez, passando-os para `join` à medida em que são encontrados).

Answer (score 5):

Tirando proveito do tamanho conhecido:

```
str = "abcd456f89d1"
novo = str[0:2] + ":" + str[2:4] + ":" + str[4:6] + ":" + str[6:8] + ":" + str[8:10] + ":" + str[10:12]
print(novo)
```

Saída:

```
ab:cd:45:6f:89:d1
```

---

E esta segunda maneira é bem explícita em refletir a intenção do programador (quebrar a string em pares de caracteres e concatená-los intercalando com `:`), desde que seja uma string sem formatação prévia, composta inteiramente por dígitos hexadecimais.

Também acho limpo que a solução se baseie somente em manipular substrings da string inicial, sem conversão de tipo:

```
import functools
str = "abcd456f89d1"
pares = [str[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(str), 2)]
novo = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + ":" + b, pares)
print(novo)
```

Saída:

```
ab:cd:45:6f:89:d1
```

Comment: O primeiro exemplo está otimo, já sabe qual o formato do valor na "entrada", então não tem o porque fazer coisas mirabolantes, o slice resolve perfeitamente.

Comment: A que me agradou foi essa: `novo = str[0:2] + ":" + str[2:4] + ":" + str[4:6] + ":" + str[6:8] + ":" + str[8:10] + ":" + str[10:12]` - não por ser oneliner, mais pelo fato de acessar diretamente pelas posições conhecidas.

Comment: Essa que o @Bacco e o @GuilhermeNascimento gostaram e a resposta do @hkotsubo `bytes.fromhex(mac.replace('-', '')).hex(':')` são as melhores soluções.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode separar a string que deseja (supondo que a mesma será sempre um endereço mac válido e que já houve o tratamento colocado na pergunta antes) e utilizar [compreensão de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mac = "b0be762931b3"
# Percorremos a string pulando sempre o próximo caractere 
# (pois estamos usando i + 1, então já lemos ele na última iteração) 
# e, ao final, concatenamos nossa lista de 
# resultados com ':' utilizando o método join. Lembrando que o 
# tamanho da string está sendo considerado com "-1", pois
# estamos sempre um item a frente.
':'.join(['{}{}'.format(mac[i], mac[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(mac) - 1, 2)])
```

#### Explicação sobre o que foi feito acima:

Esse tipo de declaração nos permite criar listas em apenas uma linha se preferível, mas funciona como criar uma lista com um laço de repetição comum (pense num `for`) adicionando um valor em uma lista e retornando-a ao final. Um exemplo:

```
def gera_lista(tamanho_lista):
    resultado = []
    for i in range(tamanho_lista):
        resultado.append(i)
        
    return resultado
```

A função acima pode ser escrita como:

```
tamanho_lista = 5
[i for i in range(tamanho_lista)]
```

O método [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) fará com que os valores que estão na nova lista gerada sejam concatenados e "separados" pelo valor que está no objeto de string no qual foi chamado (desde que o elemento seja uma string. Essa conversão para string pode ser feita com [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), que retorna uma string representando o valor do objeto). Se usarmos o exemplo acima e juntarmos os valores em uma string, separando-os por vírgula:

```
','.join([str(i) for i in range(5)])
```

Teremos o resultado:

```
"0,1,2,3,4"
```

Antes de escrevermos `for i in...` na declaração usando compreensão de listas, podemos inserir uma [expressão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#:%7E:text=Uma%20express%C3%A3o%20em%20linguagens%20de,%2C%20produz%20(retorna)%20um%20valor). O uso do [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) dentro do laço de repetição é apenas para juntar as strings e retornar uma nova string concatenada com os dois caracteres, mas poderia ter sido feito de formas diferentes (como `mac[i] + mac[i + 1]` ou `f'{mac[i]}{mac[i + 1]}'`).

Agora, para não pularmos nenhum caractere ou deixar algum de fora, usamos um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) e chamamos seu construtor com um terceiro argumento de `step`. Esse argumento diz ao iterator de "quanto em quanto" vamos iterar pelos valores gerados. Pense na definição como:

```
range(começo, fim, passo)
```

Juntando cada função, usos de expressões acima e um pouco de lógica, temos o resultado:

```
':'.join(['{}{}'.format(mac[i], mac[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(mac) - 1, 2)])
```

Ao executar com o valor exemplificado na pergunta, teremos a saída:

```
b0:be:76:29:31:b3
```

E com o tratamento completo (já considerado na pergunta):

```
import re
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
novo = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","",mac)
print(':'.join([novo[i] + novo[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(novo) - 1, 2)]))
```

A saída será:

```
b5:b4:74:22:37:bc
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema, é percorrendo a string e colocar um comando condicional `if` para fazer a inserção do caractere <kbd>:</kbd> no local indicado pelo contador, neste caso toda vez que houver um múltiplo do número 2.

Para descobrir quais valores são múltiplos do algarismo 2(dois) utilizamos o operador resto da divisão, representado por `%`.

A implementação seria assim:

```
mac_number = 'b0be762931b3'
formated_mac_number = ''
for i, item in enumerate(mac_number):
    if i % 2 == 0 and i > 0:
        formated_mac_number += ':'
    formated_mac_number += item
print(formated_mac_number)
# b0:be:76:29:31:b3
```

Usando a função [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) como uma maneira de contar e iterar os itens da `string` que desejamos percorrer. Isso vai auxiliar na condição de quando efetuar a inserção do valor <kbd>:</kbd>

---

Outra possibilidade seria utilizar apenas um contador para efetuar a tarefa. Da seguinte forma:

```
mac_number = 'b0be762931b3'
formated_mac_number = ''
for i in range(len(mac_number)):
    if i % 2 == 0 and i > 0:
        formated_mac_number += ':'
    formated_mac_number += mac_number[i]
print(formated_mac_number)
# b0:be:76:29:31:b3
```

Para auxiliar nesta implementação, temos a função [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), que vai setar como valor máximo o tamanho da string `mac_number` com o auxilio da função [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) que vai nos fazer percorrer todos os caracteres começando no índice `0` ao `len(mac_number)` aí basta percorrer a string `mac_number` através do valor do índice `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Outra solução é remover os caracteres indesejados da string e a converter em um vetor de caracteres(lista) para então iterar por esse vetor inserindo o caractere ":", nos lugares apropriados, isso se **antecipadamente levar em conta** o quanto o vetor irá se modificara durante a operação portando o seu tamanho se aumentará, a uma taxa calculável, enquanto faz a iteração.

A cada dois caracteres o vetor de caracteres será aumentado em um caractere ":" , ou seja ao final da operação o comprimento do vetor resultante será uma vez o comprimento do vetor de entrada mais a sua metade de seu comprimento, onde tem que ainda ser descontado o último caractere pois não se adicionado ":" ao final da string. Supondo que `s` seja o vetor de entrada já purgado então ao final da operação o tamanho do vetor resultante terá o comprimento:

```
tamanho_do_vetor_resultante = (len(s) - 1) + (len(s) - 1) / 2
```

Ou simplificando e truncando:

```
tamanho_do_vetor_resultante = int((len(s) - 1) * 1.5)
```

No caso:

```
#O código não testa se o endereço mac tem a quantidade de dígitos correta. Implemente aparte.

mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"

s = list(mac.replace("-",""))                    #Purga os caracteres indesejados.

for i in range(2, int((len(s) - 1) * 1.5), 3):   #Para i variando de dois ao comprimento projetado do vetor resultado a cada três elementos(não dois pois temos que levar em conta o último ":" inserido)...
  s.insert(i,":")                                #...insira na posição i o caractere ":" .   
  
print("".join(s))                                #Imprima o resultado como string.
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Ide.One](https://ideone.com/96tSVy)</sup>

Comment: Por que não `for i in range(2, len(str), 2)` ou o que quer que funcione nesse sentido? O segundo `2` é o _step_. Fica mais clara a intenção a meu ver :)

Comment: @Piovezan, porque estou inserindo enquanto itero pelo vetor e tamanho dele expande a cada iteração.

Comment: Ahhhh bem observado. Vou deixar meu comentário aqui caso alguém cometa o mesmo engano que eu :)

Answer (score 0):

Reutilizando seu código inicial, podemos fazer assim.

```
import re

mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
novo = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]","",mac)
tamanho = len(novo)

formatado = ':'.join(novo[i:i+2] for i in range(0,tamanho,2))

print(formatado)
```

Mas podemos facilitar um pouco mais a leitura substituindo a expressão regurar por algo mais simples, caso vc tenha certeza do formato inicial seja sempre como o da variavel `mac`

```
mac = "b5b4-7422-37bc"
novo = mac.replace("-","")
tamanho = len(novo)

formatado = ':'.join(novo[i:i+2] for i in range(0,tamanho,2))

print(formatado)
```

Sobre a formação, é usado o `range` que recebe 3 argumentos.

- O primeiro indica que deve iniciar em 0;
- O segundo é o limite    máximo, que no nosso caso é o tamanho da
  variavél `novo`;
- O terceiro    estamos indicando como ele vai fazer a contagem, no
  nosso caso,    pulando de dois em dois;

Com isso o `for` vai iterar de dois em dois nos characters de `novo` até o final dele, o `join` vai "juntar" esses caracteres com ":" formatando assim o `mac` no formato desejado.